# Git ingoring other project folders & Only commit my Folder's changes

Tags: git

In our Git repository, there are four projects javaproject, liferayproject & htmlproject, restapilist. Many developers are working on it. When I clone it brings all the folders. Is there a way I can only clone a part this repository?

Or Can I create similar file like .gitignore which can be kept locally which can ignore other folder changes

Comment: You can do a sparse checkout but it seems you have put too much into one repository, in general it is better to have 1 repository per project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)